# iMessage doesn't work on my devices

Tags: apple-id

iMessage and FaceTime throw an activation error any time I try to login on both of my devices (Mac Mini 2011 and iPad Pro 9.7). This happens since Dec 20 and I can't fix it.

It looks that I have tried everything that is told when you google for "imessage authentication/activation error" / "could not sign in to imessage" / "iMessage doesn't work" and other stuff:

- obviously reboot
- set the time to auto-since with Apple servers
- reset nvram on Mac
- remove sim from iPad and put it back in
- reset network settings
- logout and log back in to iCloud via System Preferences
- change Apple ID password, disable/enable two-step auth
- "wait 24 hours"
- tried both with home Wi-Fi and via cellular data on iPad
- finally... created NEW Apple ID first on Mac, then created another one on iPad.

... and it doesn't work.

[image]

All my software is up to date and I can successfully use iCloud storage and everything else that includes interaction with Apple ID - except of FaceTime and iMessage.

The curious thing is that it stopped working simultaneously on both my devices. The more curious thing is the impossibility to use another Apple ID - I have created three new Apple IDs trying to fix the problem.

I don't have an iPhone and never had.

This sounds ridiculous to happen at all. Has anyone encountered the similar problem?

I'm not sure what could have triggered that. I haven't changed my devices recently. I don't use VPN.

Comment: This is not a solution, but just another suggestion: Do you use a different ID with iTunes? If you do, somehow your devices are trying to connect to iMessage via that account. I have also noticed a distinct change in how iCloud behaves and have had to sign out and sign in multiple times in the last couple of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have fixed it long ago, but forgot that I asked my question here.

The problem was that for whatever reason, Apple has blocked my iMessage, by mistake. It was actually procedure intended to help against spammers, but seems that it has encountered a false positive on my account.

After a phone call to Apple, they unblocked my iMessage and I had never run into that problem since.

---

It's funny though, that creating a new Apple ID didn't help that time. Appears that Apple is tracking what Apple ID's are used on every device for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are signed in to both devices with using the same Apple ID then call Apple Support and have them check if your iMessage is registered and active. If so then they can help you fix it from there.

If you are not registered or activated then they can have you re-register and that should fix the issue.